# Deleting the last n elements of numpy array works only in some cases

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on the following script, which is conceived to be later inserted in a while loop, in which I have a total "x" counter (tot_x) that must not exceed the max "x" (max_x) value admitted. The tot_x is meant to be updated at each iteration by adding to it the size of a numpy array, of which "a" is an example. If the size of "a" is such that tot_x exceeds the threshold, I want to create a shorter version of the array "a", called "b", which perfectly fits the remaining gap between max_x and tot_x. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

tot_x = 200
max_x = 300

a = np.arange(1030,1200)
tot_x = tot_x + a.size

if tot_x > max_x:
    b = a[:-(a.size-(max_x-tot_x))]
    tot_x = (tot_x-a.size) + b.size
```

The problem is that if I run the code as it is, the "b" array is not created correctly, i.e. it has a dimension of 0, whilst if I remove the updating of the tot_x and the if statement, the "b" array is created exactly as I want. Here is the example of the code functioning for the "b" array:

```
import numpy as np

tot_time = 200
max_time = 300

a = np.arange(1030,1200)
b = a[:-(a.size-(max_time-tot_time))]
tot_time = (tot_time-a.size) + b.size
```

Where is the problem??
Thanks a lot

Comment: If I understood correctly you want the spill over of `a` beyond `max_x` to go into `b`. If that is the case, have you consider trying `b = a[-(tot_x - max_x):]` and then update the length of `b` to be `tot_x -= max_x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between the two isn't the if statement, it's the value of tot_x/tot_time.  You reassign the value of `tot_x` to `tot_x + a` in the first, but not the second.  As a result, even though the code inside the if statement is being hit, it computes to `b = a[:-240]`, which is correctly evaluating to an empty array.

I think what you're after can be accomplished by the replacing `b = a[:-(a.size-(max_x-tot_x))]` with `b = a[:-(a.size-(tot_x-max_x))]`.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, you made me realise the problem. The solution that works is indeed `b = a[:-(tot_x-max_x)]`.

Comment: @FrancescoLombardi If this answer was helpful you may accept it. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)